# Show questions with bounties

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

How do I list all questions with bounties?

Or better yet, all bounty questions with no chosen answer and the tag "android"

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [index page](http://stackoverflow.com), click the [Featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab. Or, for specific tags, on the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), click the [Featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=featured&pagesize=50) tab.

[image]